# How do you install octomap on Fuerte in linux?

Tags: ros, linux, octomap, octomap-mapping, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at the [octomap](http://ros.org/wiki/octomap_mapping) instructions, it is not clear to me what I have to do to install the "pre-built packages" on linux -- sorry I don't use linux much so this maybe very clear to others.

What are the commands to install the correct packages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34377/how-do-you-install-octomap-on-fuerte-in-linux?/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2012-05-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For just installing octomap as a stand-alone library, run

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-octomap
```

To install octomap, ROS integration, and octomap_server run

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-octomap ros-fuerte-octomap-mapping
```

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2